# Question from "Geometry of syzygies" by Eisenbud

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let 7 points in $\mathbb {P}^3$ in general linear position, i.e. no 3 are on a line, no 4 are one a plane, etc.

If I denote with $R $ the ring associated to this variety show that

$H_R (0)=1$

$H_R (1)=4$

$H_R (d)=7$, when $d\geq 2$

$H_R (d) $ is the Hilbert function

Looks very intuitive.

I found this question in "Geometry of syzygies" by Eisenbud

Comment: Since Eisenbud left this to the reader in an introductory book for students, I don’t know if it’s really a research question. Maybe ask on math.stackexchange instead?